# How to bring back missing options on System Settings

Tags: apt, package-management, pulseaudio, official-repositories

I am newbie in Linux and I was trying to fix problem with skype (it is muted) and I accidentally removed almost all my applications ( I don't have anything to control my desktop settings, mouse, keyboard etc. ) from "System Settings"! How can I get it back? I didn't do backup or anything like this. I wrote these three commands and they seem to have cause the issue:

```
 killall pulseaudio
 sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio
 sudo apt-get install esound
```

Comment: These 3 commands would not do anything as far as your other installed packages are concerned. Can you provide more info like what other packages you have removed and installed? What error is showing when you run any command or any application?

Comment: I installed pulseaudio, synaptic, skype and some plugins like google hangout's ( and hangouts are not muted like skype ). I have not removed any important/default packages. Propably when I wrote this command to remove pulseaudio, terminal have asked to remove some other packages(?) and I just made fast decision and I made mistake. My Linux installation is pretty fresh so I don't mind even to just use backup, but I don't have it.

Comment: Ok, good. When you remove **pulseaudio** then the other packages that were removed are called **dependencies** and those are not needed for other packages to run otherwise those won't be removed at the first place by **apt**. Now coming back to your problem could you tell why you have removed **pulseaudio** and whats the exact problem you are facing currently?

Comment: I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6P_PC9LZslU
and this is what I am facing right now :-)
http://i.stack.imgur.com/jG8lu.png

Comment: Ok, i think you have removed some other important packages in the process. Now run this command in the terminal **sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop**, reboot your computer and then check again.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Now I have to try fix my skype, pulseaudio doesn't recognize skype in recording and playback.

Comment: No problem. Now select my answer having the above command as the answer to your question so that others can know that your issue has been resolved. On a side note open a new question regarding your problem with skype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This will bring the missing options back on **System Settings**.